# C - Accepting User Input + Printing from an Array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I am trying to receive user input from the keyboard, to fill a matrix. This is what I have come up with so far and am unsure as to why it is not outputting the user input.

Edit: I changed [nRows][nCols] in the for loop to the appropriate values of the actual loops. (k,o),(i,j). Also changed variable name o to p as o is similar to 0, as suggested by a user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
int nRows;
int nCols;


//Setting up the Grid
printf("Enter number of Rows: \n");
scanf("%i",&nRows);
/*
for(int k = 0; k <= nRows; ++k){
    printf("Fill Rows: \n");
    scanf("%i",&nRows);
}
*/

printf("Enter number of Columns: \n");
scanf("%i",&nCols);
/*
for(int k = 0; k <= nCols; ++k){
    printf("Fill Cols: \n");
    scanf("%i",&nCols);
}
*/

int matrix[nRows][nCols];

for(int k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    for(int p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
        printf("Enter value for Matrix[%i][%i]: ",nRows,nCols);
        scanf("%i",&matrix[k][p]);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < nCols; ++j){
    printf("%i\t",matrix[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}

return 0;
//col[n]+row[n] == userinput

}
```

Comment: Change `matrix[nRows][nCols]` to `matrix[i][o]` and  `matrix[i][j]`  in both input and output loops. BTW, `o` is a bad variable name choice, as it is similar to `0`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank You. Problem solved

Comment: @robinhood46 Please add your edit as an answer and mark it as accepted. It helps people to see easily that the problem  was solved.

Comment: when calling the `scanf()` function, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: `printf("Enter value for Matrix[%i][%i]: ",nRows,nCols);` will confuse the user as to exactly what they are entering.   Suggest: `printf("Enter value for Matrix[%i][%i]: ", k, p);`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I changed [nRows][nCols] in the for loop to the appropriate values of the actual loops. (k,o),(i,j). Also changed variable name o to p as o is similar to 0, as suggested by a user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
int nRows;
int nCols;


//Setting up the Grid
printf("Enter number of Rows: \n");
scanf("%i",&nRows);
/*
for(int k = 0; k <= nRows; ++k){
    printf("Fill Rows: \n");
    scanf("%i",&nRows);
}
*/

printf("Enter number of Columns: \n");
scanf("%i",&nCols);
/*
for(int k = 0; k <= nCols; ++k){
    printf("Fill Cols: \n");
    scanf("%i",&nCols);
}
*/

int matrix[nRows][nCols];

for(int k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    for(int p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
        printf("Enter value for Matrix[%i][%i]: ",nRows,nCols);
        scanf("%i",&matrix[k][p]);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < nCols; ++j){
    printf("%i\t",matrix[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}

return 0;
//col[n]+row[n] == userinput

}
```